# GitHub 2 People commit changes to same branch

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

If 2 people are working on the same branch in GitHub and consider we have a file `"abc.js"` in the branch, and both are making their own changes to the same file `"abc.js"`. Now while committing 1st person commits and pushes his changes on to git, and if the 2nd person wants to commit his local changes he hits a pull request. Now what will happen to the changes which the 2nd person was working on `"abc.js"` file? Will the code merge??

Comment: When the second person pushes she gets the error [Updates were rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Updates+were+rejected) so she must first do pull and pull does [merge](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging#_basic_merging) or [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Comment: This a completely testable hypothetical. Why not just try it yourself and see? Programmers try things.

Answer (score 0):

To a large extent, the pull request part of the story is irrlevant; we are really just talking about merging.

If two people work on the same file, their code might merge and it might not. Git thinks in terms of lines — which actually turns out to mean a line and its immediate neighborhood. In a 20-line file, if Alice edits line 1 and Bob edits line 20, that is mergeable without a conflict. If they both edit line 1, it isn't.

Comment: "their code might merge and it might not" - it's *mergeable*, but afaik it doesn't merge by itself? a user action is needed, right? I think that was what was asked.

Comment: @eis Question says: “What will happen to the changes which the 2nd person was working on "abc.js" file? Will the code merge??” To me that asks if merge is possible